# How to change cart for users in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

I need to create a link that change's a user's cart with one that is expired.

this is what i tried, but it doesn't work

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_'))
    define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', (getcwd().'/../../') );//prima del require_once
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/config.inc.php');

...

$this->context->cookie->id_cart = 6;
$this->context->cart = new Cart(6);
$this->context->cookie->write();
$this->context->cookie->update();
Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order');
```

Answer (score 0):

what about : $this->context->cart->id = 6 ?